# SQL Server debugging rights for standard developers

Tags: sql-server, debugging

I guess it is not possible to debug a query in SQL Server if the user is not granted with sysadmin rights, hence I get the Error 229. I understand that being a sysadmin for a developer is unacceptable (my DBA won't grant me that right for sure), so is there any kind of workaround for a developer to debug an SQL Server query without being granted as sysadmin? In my opinion, debugging in SQL Server should not be something that only sysadmins are allowed to do..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **must** have syadmin rights in order to be able to debug SQL (see [How to: Set SQL Server Permissions for Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1bhybwz%28v=VS.90%29.aspx))

Debugging SQL isn't something that should be done on production machines - [in the words of Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s0fk6z6e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> Debugging sessions often run for long periods of time while you investigate the operations of several Transact-SQL statements. Locks, such as update locks, that are acquired by the session might be held for extended periods, until the session has ended or the transaction is committed or rolled back.

**Definitely** not a good idea for production machines.

(I'm assuming that this was for a production SQL server - restricting permissions for devs on non production servers seems kinda pointless)

If you need to debug against on a production machine because of the live data then just do the debugging on a mirror / backup of the live data.

Comment: Well it shows once more that Microsoft is often far away from reality in big enterprise. How about a scenario where you have a shared test infrastructure for several departments. Really wanna give a user who has to test some code sysadmin rights ? Some of their decisions are stunning given the fact how long they are in business.

Comment: @nojetlag Thats a perfect example of a scenario where you **don't** want users debugging SQL as its highly likely that debugging will have an adverse impact on other users of that infrastructure (i.e. other departments), hence the requirement that you be sysadmin to do so.

Comment: I think we have different perspectives, sharing infrastructure vs coordinating test efforts. If my testing window is in the morning and yours is in the afternoon, as a sysadmin I can mess up the whole setup when I actually just should debug a bit code. If you live in an apartment complex and i have workers coming to fix my flat you don't want them to have the master key for that, enough if they have the key for my flat ;-)

Comment: @nojetlag You can still mess up the system in the afternoon if you forget to end the debugging session

Answer (score -1):

**You only need execution rights** (as far as I know)  - I'm certainly no sysadmin but I can debug SQL

Comment: I have execution rights. But I can't debug the SPs.