# Debug SQL Server queries with SQL Login

Tags: sql-server, debugging, permissions

I want to allow my SQL Server logins to debug while windows login is disable or haven't SysAdmin Role.

When I disable Windows Login, I get this error:

[image]

When I revoke sysAdmin role form it, I get this error:

[image]

What special solution do you have for allow some logins to have debug permission?

- tip : My problem is on non-Production server.
- tip : My debuggers login have SysAdmin but They're not Windows Logins.

Comment: The error says that you must have sysadmin role, so why are you revoking it?

Comment: @JamesZ, I want my users login with their SQL Server logins, so I needs to disable any windows logins(Or have windows login without any permissions).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server debugging rights for standard developers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884171/sql-server-debugging-rights-for-standard-developers)

Comment: Actually I haven't problem with sysAdmin permission, I grant sysAdmin to them and They can debug with their login too. All of my problem occur when I disable windows login.

Comment: For example I have a login "A" with sysAdmin role, "A" is able to debugging, But When "Administrator" disabled then "A" get error in debugging too!